# No value given for one or more required parameters when using the `UPDATE` command

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm trying to update my records using the `UPDATE` command. I get this error:

> No value given for one or more required parameters.

Here's my code:

```
 Private Sub saveOle_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles saveOle.Click
    Try
        Using conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\samplelangtowalangya.mdb;")
            conn.Open()
            Dim command As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE sample SET ewan = @ewan, ko = @ko, sayo = @sayo, hehehe = @hehehe WHERE Number_of_Employees = @Number_of_Employees", conn)
            With command.Parameters
                .AddWithValue("@ewan", ewan.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@ko", ko.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@sayo", sayo.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@hehehe", hehehe.Text)
                command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With

            MessageBox.Show("Employee's Informations Successfuly Updated!", "INFO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            command.Dispose()
            conn.Close()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR12", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

The `Number_of_Employees` is my ID and primary key.

Comment: The SQL has 5 named parameters and you only provide 4.  You need to supply a value for the named value in the where clause or else what will the resulting SQL look like?

Comment: Oh yes. I tried to place my `ID` first before the `@ewan`. The I placed it after the four fields. It works now, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried to placed my `ID` after the four fields, and it works fine now :)

```
 Private Sub saveOle_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles saveOle.Click
    Try
        Using conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\samplelangtowalangya.mdb;")
            conn.Open()
            Dim command As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE sample SET ewan = @ewan, ko = @ko, sayo = @sayo, hehehe = @hehehe WHERE Number_of_Employees = @Number_of_Employees", conn)
            With command.Parameters
                .AddWithValue("@ewan", ewan.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@ko", ko.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@sayo", sayo.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@hehehe", hehehe.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@Number_of_Employees", IDtext.Text)
            End With
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MessageBox.Show("Employee's Informations Successfuly Updated!", "INFO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            command.Dispose()
            conn.Close()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR12", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```